Kendo Grid add and array of element to to a table with Javascript
I have a form to add admin user to a site. Multiple users can be added at once.  OnSuccess, I need to append the users to a Kendo Grid (Table).  How can I append all three users when the AJAX response looks like this.
{
    "Result": true,
     "Message": "Success!",
     "AccountRoleId": 106,
     "Users": [
         {
             "FirstName": "Joe",
             "LastName": "Smith",
             "Email": "test@foo.com",
             "Status": 1
         },
         {
             "FirstName": "John",
             "LastName": "Doe",
             "Email": "john@doe.com",
             "Status": 1
         },
         {
             "FirstName": "Al",
             "LastName": "Jones",
             "Email": "al@jones.com",
             "Status": 1
         }
     ]
 }

This script will not work I keep getting a single entry of undefined undefined, added to the Kendo table after the form is submitted.
var newRow = { FirstName: response.Users.FirstName, LastName: response.Users.LastName, Email: response.Users.Email, Status: response.Users.Status };

var grid = $("#UsersTable-").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.add(newRow);


You have to access the property Users which has an array. This will render the grid.
var grid = $("#UsersTable-").data("kendoGrid");
if(response.Result) {
    response.Users.forEach((item) => {
        item.Status = item.Status || 0;
    });
    grid.dataSource.add(response.Users);
} else {
    console.error('unable to fetch data');
}


Thanks Naren Murali, this is so close.  unfortunately, I'm getting "Status" is undefined

@esoteric There is no status line in the question, please share the line where the error occours, if possible a working example

Naren Maruli the "Status" is in the response for the user records, there is a value
for each but for some reason Kendo is telling me it is undefined. {
"Result": true,
"Message": "Success!",
"AccountRoleId": 106,
"Users": [
{
"FirstName": "Joe",
"LastName": "Smith",
"Email": "test@foo.com",
"Status": 1
},

@esoteric updated answer, with a default value for Status if not present

Thanks Naren Maruli, still have the issue, there is always a status value,  the existing code was a single select box and it was updated to a multiselect.  Everything is good on the backend .  If I refresh the page the table is correct.  It seems I am not adding the response users correctly.
